# How to setup samba as a domain controller?

Tags: samba

I would like to setup samba as a domain controller. Can anyone help me with clear installation procedure and steps? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official document from samba: [Chapter 4. Domain Control](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/samba-pdc.html). It's long and winding but might be a good reference.

The [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-dc.html) will be very useful in setting it up. From the link:

**Samba as a Domain Controller**
Although it cannot act as an Active Directory Primary Domain Controller (PDC), a Samba server can be configured to appear as a Windows NT4-style domain controller. A major advantage of this configuration is the ability to centralize user and machine credentials. Samba can also use multiple backends to store the user information.

It's for 10.04 but all the commands and settings in the link are still working for 11.04.