# Ubuntu Server Roaming Profile for XP pro

Tags: 12.04, server, shared-folders, domain-server

I'am new to ubuntu or linux server OS. What I want to accomplish is to have an Ubuntu 12 Server running for my workplace. We currently have atleast ten employees and I want them to have their own roaming profile, their own shared folders which is accessable by the administrator and my manager. My workstations are all running Windows XP pro, and you could include a setup for Mandatory type of profile that would be GREAT.

//Summary of all the setups

1. Ubuntu as a PDC.
2. Use roaming profile for 10 employees
3. Each has their own shared folder that is accessable by authenticated user and of course the manager.

Comment: I fail to see a problem and see only statements ;-)  If you want to set up shares: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba is the normal method. `roaming profile` is a Windows concept and does not seem to apply to your server (I think)(since users can access the Linux system from anywhere after providing username and passwordt :) (

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is a question similar to: [How to setup samba as a domain controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47024/how-to-setup-samba-as-a-domain-controller)

Or

- https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-dc.html
- http://arnabonweb.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/tutorial-configuring-ubuntu-as-pdc/