# Ubuntu active directory like login

Tags: login, sync

In a configuration of various users and machines is it possible to sync or do something similar to windows domain accounts where every user can login on every machine with the same domain login? Basically like a domain login in Windows? I don't know where to start searching for the information I need to do this. These are all linux machines I'm working with.

Comment: I think @Zook isn't limiting it to Windows's solution of domain controllers. I think that any solution that allows a bunch of people to enter their password into multiple computers and have password changes change their password on all computers would be fine.

Comment: @Zook can you guys us some examples of things that need to be synchronized?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-authentication.html.en

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways I can think of to do this:

- You can use LDAP to have network-wide user passwords. I think Ubuntu uses PAM for logins, so you'd use a PAM LDAP module for logins. If your network is good enough, you can also use an NFS file server if you want to have a consistent home directory for each user on all computers. You can even have dumb client computers with no hard drives (perhaps spend the money on more RAM instead) which use PXE to load from a server an Ubuntu boot image configured to use the proper LDAP and NFS servers.
- You can [have SAMBA act as a Windows domain controller](https://askubuntu.com/q/47024/616451) and have the client machines use PAM with SAMBA to authenticate. This has the benefit that you can more easily add Windows machines to the network later on if you want to.

I'm sure there are other methods.